# How can I implement more than 1 filter in a report separated with AND / OR and other Bool operands

Tags: reporting

How can I implement more than 1 filter in a report separated with AND / OR and other Bool operands.
If I add a new filter, I've only AND as choice. I want to use also others.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

In Filters, beside Add filter button there is a dropdown button named `Filter Logic`, Using which you can modify your condition.

[image]

Filter logic would look something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When customizing a report you have the filters at the top NeXT to the 'filter' button there is a 'down' arrow where you can add 'filter logic'.